# NPM module not found despite linking successfully and being downloaded successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I locally developed an NPM package and was able to link it successfully on my own computer. When I tried to do the same on a remote computer, despite linking successfully, I would get an error saying my module was not found which didn't make sense.

I tried to solve this by publishing the package to npm, and then downloading it remotely. I did this both locally, and remotely to make sure it was working.

Not only did it not work remotely, but also suddenly broke locally. The module couldn't be found.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `dist` folder where I was putting my built files for the package happened to also be in my `.gitignore`.

This meant that whenever I linked or published the package, the `dist` folder would be excluded, and that the module couldn't be found even though everything was working as it should.

The solution was to make an `.npmignore` file and put the following inside

```
!dist
```

This would make npm acknowledge the package even if it was being ignored.